# PUT and DELETE route is not showing in laravel route list on apiResource

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-9, laravel-api

I added apiResource routes in my api.php file. Although it shows all the resourceful routes for product/category, it is not showing the routes for PUT and DELETE methods in the case of products routes.

Showing **404 not found error.**

Any help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are showing. They are third and fourth from the bottom of the listed routes.

Comment: they do not accepting params, hence the update and delete method not working and causing 404 not found error on PUT and DELETE.

Comment: I believe it because you have `/` name and it converts as empty parameter (it kinda ignores prefix). Try to manually set parameter as product with `Route::apiResource('/', ProductController::class)->parameters(['' => 'product']);`

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka I also tried outside of route group prefix, Route::apiResource('product/', ProductController::class); still no luck. I am wondering why.

Comment: @Peppermintology in Product model id is not fillable.

Comment: Hm, just checked in my test app - cannot confirm it's not working. What do you mean by no luck - there are still no param in routes or 404 response or both?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Thanks @IharAliakseyenka my apiResource name was / too and using ->parameters worked I can see my PUT route is now expecting a param

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the missing parameter names using the [parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters) method.

```
Route::prefix('products')->group(function() {
    Route::apiResource('/', \App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class)
        ->parameters(['' => 'product']);
    Route::apiResource('/categories', \App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController::class);
});
```

That should give you the following:

[image: routes image]

Note that it is a convention to make your resources plural rather than singular.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish a lot using scoped nested resources and shallow nesting:

```
Route::apiResource('products', ProductController::class);
Route::apiResource('products.categories', ProductCategoryController::class);
```

[image]

```
Route::apiResource('products', ProductController::class);
Route::apiResource('products.categories', ProductCategoryController::class)->shallow();
```

[image]